# Creating anonymous types based on lambda expression

Tags: lambda, anonymous-types, c#, datasource

I'm trying to create a Fluent Interface to the Winforms Datagrid. This should allow me to use a typed datasource and easy use of properties of properties (Order.Custom.FullName)

I'm adding the columns on initialization and trying to set the property to use there:

```
dgv.With<Order>().Column("Client Name").On(x => x.Client.FullName);
```

The original question then poses itself when setting the Datasource:

```
dgv.SetTypedDatasource<T>(IList<Order> orders)
```

A big problem here is that Generic Controls are not possible (I guess), so that T cannot be specified for the class, but has to be specified per method...

I want to create a list of anonymous types, based on a given property in a lambda expression:

something like:

```
ProcessList<Client>(clientList, x => x.FullName);
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

[Edit] Note that in practice, the expressions will be set earlier, and will be fetched elsewhere...

```
public void ProcessList<T>(IList<T> sourceList, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    var list =
        (from T x
         in sourceList
         select new { expression })
         .ToList();

    // process list ....  grid.DataSource = list;
}
```

So, I would like to create anonymous types based on the given expression. I know I can evaluate that expression to retrieve the correct properties.

I'm kinda stuck, is something like this possible?

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not quite sure, what do you want in your anonymous type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, with a simple call to `Select` you can come very close:

```
ProcessList(clientList.Select(x => new { x.FullName }));

...

public void ProcessList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    // process list ... T will be an anonymous type by now
    grid.DataSource = list;
}
```

(That assumes you don't need the *original* list in `ProcessList` as well. If you do, move the select into there.)

Comment: Note that if that is a winform grid, it will need a ToList() - webform grids are happy with IEnumerable, though.

Comment: Still, not quite what I need, I'll explain a bit more in the question.

Comment: @Marc, yes I forgot that line :)

Answer (score 2):

isn't that just `grid.DataSource = sourceList.AsQueryable().Select(expression).ToList();`

Note that it would be better to introduce a second generic, such that the list is typed:

```
    public static void ProcessList<TSource, TValue>(
        IList<TSource> sourceList,
        Func<TSource, TValue> expression)
    {
        grid.DataSource = sourceList.Select(expression).ToList();
    }
```

Note I switched from `Expression<...>` to just `Func<...>`, as it seemed to serve no purpose.